# SQL BIG QUERY - Single row to multiple rows

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to split 1 row into multiple rows.

Example:

```
This is what I have :
Row date           enquiry calls enuiryL callsL
1   2020-01-01      25     5      45     20

This is what I need:
Row date          Type        Thisyear   LastYear
1   2020-01-01    enquiry        25         45
2   2020-01-01    Calls          5          20
```

Any help appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: What you want to do is create a "View". https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use arrays and `unnest()`:

```
select row_number() over (order by date, type desc) as row,
       t.date, el.type, el.thisyear, el.lastyear
from t cross join
     unnest(array[struct('enquiry' as type, enquiry as thisyear, enquiryl as lastyear),
                  struct('calls' as type, calls as thisyear, callsl as lastyear)
                 ]
           ) el;
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT date, type, thisyear, lastyear
FROM (
  SELECT date, 
    [
      STRUCT('enquiry' AS type, enquiry AS thisyear, enquiryl AS lastyear),
      ('calls', calls, callsl)
    ] lines
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
) t, t.lines
```

with output

```
Row date        type        thisyear    lastyear     
1   2020-01-01  enquiry     25          45   
2   2020-01-01  calls       5           20
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `union all`:

```
select row_number() over(order by row, type) row, date, type, this_year, last_year
from (
    select row, date, 'enquiry' type, enquiry this_year, enquiryL last_year
    union all
    select row, date, 'calls' type, calls, callsL
) t
order by row
```